# How to calculate LFW accuracy of face recognition model?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

In my research I have observed many of the face recognition algorithms propose their model accuracy interms of LFW dataset accuracy. I understood that LFW is a open source database and I did download that.

I have developed my own DNN model implemented for face recognition which is similar to [facenet](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet) architecture. Can anyone help with the procedure to calculate LFW accuracy of my model?

Comment: You can use Cross-Validation and check your model performance.

Answer (score 0):

FaceNet should embed pictures in a high dimensional space in such a way that similar pictures are close (wrt to a given distance metric) to each other and different images are farther apart.

That means, to calculate the accuracy of your model you need to find your threshold distance *d* which delivers the highest accuracy. Given such a distance, you can calculate the accuracy like you would do for a [binary classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_of_binary_classifiers). That is, the accuracy is the "Number of correctly classified pairs/Number of pairs"

For example, consider the three images A1,A2 of person A and B1 of person B. And say your DNN embedds the images such that the pair-wise L2 distance (i.e., the euclidean distance) is 1,3, and 7. Then you can see that if use a distance threshold of 2 you get 100% accuracy, and otherwise only 66%.

```
+----------+--------------+-------------+------+------+
|   Pair   | Ground Truth | L2-distance | d=2  | d=4  |
+----------+--------------+-------------+------+------+
| A1 A2    |            1 |           1 |    1 |    1 |
| A1 B1    |            0 |           3 |    0 |    1 |
| A2 B1    |            0 |           7 |    0 |    0 |
+----------+--------------+-------------+------+------+
| Accuracy |              |             | 1.00 | 0.66 |
+----------+--------------+-------------+------+------+
```

If you are using Tensorflow, you can follow David Sandberg's instructions to caculate evaluation metrics (including Accuracy) of your model [here](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/wiki/Validate-on-lfw).

**IMPORTANT:** To compare the performance of your approach to other approaches, you should follow one of the protocols of the LFW dataset. The protocols are described in detail [here](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/321923/filename/Huang_long_eccv2008-lfw.pdf) (see Section 4). Basically, they have a special view on the dataset, which asks you to report the mean accuracy + error rates on 10 folds of that dataset.